# unvisible movie clip in stage

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I have a movie clip named 'salah'. First, I want to unvisible the clip, and when the condition error I want to display it. But in first my clip always display, How I can unvisible the movie clip?
This is my code

```
import flash.text.TextFieldType;

salah.visible=false;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,lanjutproxy2); 
function lanjutproxy2(event:KeyboardEvent)
{ 
    salah.visible=false;
    if(event.charCode == 13)
    {
        if ((mgr.text == 'cache_mgr admin@smklatihan.com')&&(vishost.text == 'visible_hostname proxy.smklatihan.com'))
        {
            nextFrame();
        } else {
            salah.visible=true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```
import flash.text.TextFieldType;

salah.visible=false;
salah.includeInLayout=false;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,lanjutproxy2); 
function lanjutproxy2(event:KeyboardEvent)
{ 
    salah.visible=false;
    if(event.charCode == 13)
    {
        if ((mgr.text == 'cache_mgr admin@smklatihan.com')&&(vishost.text == 'visible_hostname proxy.smklatihan.com'))
        {
            nextFrame();
        } else {
            salah.visible=true;
            salah.includeInLayout=true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'am sorry, but I tried this code and it didn't work...The flash not know about includeInLayout...